# How do I set up a self-destructing web page?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

I'm writing a setup script for a server, and I need to show the user the login details for the server. They can be automatically redirected to a web page and I don't know any other details.

I want to make a temporary webpage that will have the login details in it, but when the user accesses it it will be deleted from disk and the webserver shuts down.

I don't mind installing python or perl or something, but if it could be done in just sh that would be great.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you mean, when the user loads the webpage, it will show the user the login details for a server and redirects to another page. As soon as the user closes the browser, the page that displayed the login details to the user should be gone? Is shutting down the webserver necessary? And from where does it fetch the login details? Some DB?

Comment: Very bad idea. The credentials will be lost if the user forgets to write the credentials down, or the power fails at the wrong moment, or the user presses Ctrl+W instead of Ctrl+C, or the user assumes that they'll be able to refer to the page again later, or ... Don't delete information until the user has acknowledged that it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that only needs bash and netcat (traditional version). It's probably really insecure, but for a trusted user it probably works ok.

Put this script in `webscript.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="wantedfile.html"
host="localhost"

while [ true ]
do
  read a
  a=`echo ${a} | sed 's/\r//'`
  if [ "${a}" == "" ]
  then
    break
  fi
  command=`echo ${a} | grep Host:`
  if [ "${command}" != "" ]
  then
    host=`echo ${a} | awk '{ print $2 }'`
  fi
done

len=`ls -la ${file} | awk '{ print $5 }'`
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
echo "Host: ${host}"
echo "Content-Length: ${len}"
echo ""
cat ${file}
rm ${file}
```

Then you just need to use netcat:

```
nc.traditional -e 'webscript.sh' -l -p 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually generate a web page with a shell script in the cgi-bin directory!  After creating the web page the script can delete itself, shut down the webserver, etc (so long as it has permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small daemon that checks the logs and when that page is hit automatically shut the server down.

Alternatively you could invoke a shell command from your page that will have login detail in it, what would that page be coded in? If it's PHP for example you could invoke a `shell_exec` statement to stop the web server process and to remove the file.